# Is there a way to simplify this case statement?

Tags: php, loops, directory, switch-statement

I have this PHP case statement

```
switch ($parts[count($parts) - 1]) {
    case 'restaurant_pos':
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages/restaurant_pos.php');
        break;
    case 'retail_pos':
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages/retail_pos.php');
        break;  
    .....

}
```

Which works great but I have many many files (like 190) and I would love to know if there is a way to make this case statement many work with anything so I dont have to do 190 case conditions. I was thinking I can use the condtion in the case and maybe see if that file is present and if so then display and if not then maybe a 404 page but i was not sure a good way to do this...any ideas would help alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not user input, you can do it like

```
$include = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
if ($include) {
    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages/'.$include.'.php')){
          include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages/'.$include.'.php';
    }
}
```

**repeating, don't do this if $include is being filled from user's input !**

Comment: Are you sure regarding `file_exists($include)`? It is just part of path. It will always be `false`.

Answer (score 15):

You can predefine file names in an array and then use `in_array` in order to check name's existence:

```
$files = array('restaurant_pos', 'retail_pos', ......);
$file = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
if (in_array($file, $files)) {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/$file.php");
}
```

Comment: The whitelist is a good concept, but manually maintaining 190 entries (that more than likely will change) is cumbersome at least. It would be preferable to build the whitelist using scandir() on the pages/ directory, and using the directory as the whitelist itself.

Comment: how would you build that whitelist using scandir()

Comment: @Tamer You can apply array_filter() on the output of scandir().

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple implementation without security checks:

```
$file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pages/".$parts[count($parts) - 1].".php";
if(file_exists($file)) include $file;
else show404();
```

To make it more secure for example you can remove slashes from `$parts[count($parts) - 1]`

Comment: As i said i've not written the security checks but you can for example remove slashes or double dots

Comment: I'll upvote as soon as the security checks are added to the example.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the file exists, and then include it.

Note that you MUST validate the contents of `$page` to be sure it doesn't include a path like `/../../../../` to attempt to read somewhere else on your filesystem if this is to be user input.

If you know, for example that all your paths will be alphanumeric with underscores, you could do:

```
$page = $parts[count($parts)] - 1;

if (preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9_]+$/i', $page)) {
  // it's okay, so include it.
  if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/$page.php") {
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pages/$page.php");
  }
}
```

Comment: the second if statement that does the preg_match ...should that go before the $page = $parts[count($parts)] - 1; or after and what exactly is it verifying

Comment: @Tamer place the `if ()` inside the `preg_match() if ()` I'll modify the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this?

```
$include_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/pages/' . $parts[count($parts) - 1] . '.php';

if (file_exists( $include_file ))
{
    include( $include_file );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_exists($path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pages/'.$parts[count($parts) - 1].'.php')
{
    include $path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to check if the given file really exists in a particular directory:

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . basename($parts[count($parts) - 1]) . '.php';
if (is_file($file)) include($file);
```